# Comparing strings with Unicode characters in C#

Tags: c#, string, unicode

As we know to compare two string with [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) characters, we append N in front of a string. Something like:

`````
N'I am the ````king'.equals(x)
`````

(In SQL server and x also contains same Unicode characters.)

This we can write in SQL Server.

But suppose I have [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) code which has a variable called `x`:

`````
string x="Hi! I am good ````'"
`````

(With some Unicode characters.)

And there is another variable, `y`, with which I need to compare this in C# code.

How can the `N` value be appended to the string with code?

Comment: The C# language doesn't have anything to do with the TSQL language.  All string comparisons in C# are Unicode comparisons.  Do not help.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you can use the == operator to perform binary equality comparison between two strings. This operator will in fact call the [`String.Equals(string a, string b)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hkt4325) static method, which will propertly handle null references, unlike the [`String.Equals(string value)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx) method.

```
if (x == y) { Console.WriteLine("The variables x and y are equal."); }
```

Should you want to have culture sensitive and/or case insensitive comparisons, you could use the [`String.Equals(string a, string b, StringComparison comparisonType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks) method and specify an appropriate value: CurrentCulture, CurrentCultureIgnoreCase, Ordinal or OrdinalIgnoreCase. (There are also InvariantCulture and InvariantCultureIgnoreCase, but the use of those is heavily discouraged)

```
if (string.Equals(x, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) { Console.WriteLine("The variables x and y are equal by using the OrdinalIgnoreCase comparison."); }
```

If you want to sort strings, you can use one of the overloads of [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare). The good practice for using [`String.Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.compare) is to always use one of the overloads where you explicitly specify [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo) or [StringComparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison). (The ones where you specify a [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo) are espacially useful if you want to perform string comparison based on a specific culture.)

Answer (score 0):

All strings in C# are Unicode strings. They are based on UTF-16 **code units** called `char`, each `char` is just a 16-bit integer.

If `x` and `y` are C# (references to) `string`s, then both

```
x == y
```

and

```
x.Equals(y)
```

perform **ordinal** equality comparisons. So `x` and `y` must be the exact same sequences of 16-bit code units in order for this to evaluate to `true`. No Unicode normalization is performed!

.NET offers other methods to do culture-dependent comparisons, or case insensitive comparisons. Those are more complex than simple ordinal comparisons. You can also Unicode normalize `x` and `y` and compare the results of that.